# Showing all rotations of the Riemann sphere are of the form $\frac{az-\bar{c}}{cz+\bar{a}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I'm trying to understand the following observation in my textbook:

> > ...in the sense that for any rotation $\phi$ of $S$, the conjugate map $$C_\infty\xrightarrow[]{\pi}S\xrightarrow[]{\phi}S\xrightarrow[]{\pi^{-1}}C_\infty$$ is a $\sigma$ isometry.  In fact, the rotations of $S$ coincide (in this sense) with the class of Mobius transformations of the form $z \rightarrow \frac{az-\overline{c}}{cz+\overline{a}}$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ $|a|^2+|c|^2=1.$

I'm trying to reason out why they are all of that form.  Consider the following:

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\pi(\phi(\pi^{-1}(z)))$$

where $$\pi(z)=\frac{z-z_0}{z+\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}}$$

This gives me the following

$$\frac{a\pi(z)+b}{c\pi(z)+d}=\frac{\phi(z)-z_0}{\phi(z)-\frac{1}{\overline{z_0}}} $$

Before I go through the torture of algebraic manipulation on the above, my goal is to show through a bunch of manipulation that $a=a,b=\overline{b}, c=c, d=\overline{a}$.

Comment: You are using many symbols without explaining them. What are $S$ and $\pi$?

Comment: It's just a transform that fixes two points $z$ and $\frac{-1}{\overline{z}}$

Comment: S is the Riemann sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put things straight: The *Riemann sphere* is an abstract idea implementing in a correct way the addition of a point  $\infty$ to ${\mathbb C}$. There are several models of this Riemann sphere, one just being your ${\mathbb C}_\infty:={\mathbb C}\cup\{\infty\}$ (together with certain exception handling rules), and another one being $S^2$ inheriting the conformal structure from its embedding in ${\mathbb R}^3$ and being related to $\bar{\mathbb C}$ via the *stereographic projection*
$$\sigma:\quad(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto{x_1+ix_2\over 1-x_3}\ ,$$
resp. $\sigma^{-1}$.

We take it for granted that rotations  of $S^2$, being conformal maps, are conjugated via $\sigma$ to certain special Moebius transformations $$T:\quad\bar{\mathbb C}\to\bar{\mathbb C}\ .$$ The question now is to characterize these transformations $T$.

A rotation  of $S^2$ which is different from the identity has two antipodal fixed points which are neither attracting nor repelling. We therefore have to find the Moebius transformations $T$ with two fixed points that are carried by $\sigma^{-1}$ to antipodal points on $S^2$, and have a "scaling factor" $\lambda$ of absolute value $1$.

Two points $p$, $q\in{\mathbb C}$ are carried to antipodal points by $\sigma^{-1}$ iff $q=-{1\over \bar p}$. It follows that the Moebius transformations $T:\>z\mapsto z'$ in question can be written as
$${z'-p\over z'+1/\bar p}=e^{i\phi}\>{z-p\over z+1/\bar p}\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $e^{i\phi}$ is the "scaling factor" mentioned above. Now solve $(1)$ for $z'$, and you will obtain $T$ in the form
$$z'=T(z)={az+b\over cz+d}$$
with certain coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. Looking at the resulting formula you will be able to recognize the forms given in your text, after  multiplying all coefficients with ${e^{-i\phi/2}\over1+|p|^2}$.

Conversely you should show that a $T$ having coefficients as in your text has fixed points $p$ and $-1/\bar p$ and a "scaling factor" $e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: Why is there a scalar factor?  Is that sine we are fixing two points?

Comment: We are not "fixing two points". The rotation of $S^2$, resp. the $T$, has two fixed points, which are *special* for this transformation. In $(1)$ these two points are moved to $0$ and $\infty$, so that $T$ appears as $T:\>w\to w'=\lambda w$ with "scaling factor" $\lambda=e^{i\phi}$.