# Show that any mapping from the extended complex plane to the Riemann Sphere back to the extended complex plane is a Möbius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation, stereographic-projections, riemann-sphere

> Definitions:
> Extended Complex Plane $\mathbb{C}^\infty = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.
> Stereographic projection: A mapping from a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the extended complex plane.
> Möbius Transformation: $z \mapsto \frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$.

> The Question:
> Starting with a point in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$, we map it to the sphere via inverse stereographic projection, then we apply a rotation of the sphere and we project it back to the extended complex plane by stereographic projection.
> a) Show that any such mapping is a Möbius Transformation. 
> b) Does every Möbius transformation arise in this way? If so, give a proof. If not, then describe the subset of Möbius transformations that are obtained from a rotation of the sphere.

Intuitively I understand what is happening, when we rotate the sphere about the $z$-axis we get a rotation of the plane, rotating about another axis will cause a translation, dilatations, etc. I drew sketches of the sphere's, complex plane and different mappings, but I am not sure how I am supposed to prove it mathematically using formulas. As for the second question I also don't know where to start.

Comment: ´WHat is your background, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427517/42969.

Comment: This is the famous SO(3)-SU(2) correspondence.

Comment: Copy-paste error $z \mapsto \frac{a+bz}{c+dz}$ (with $z$ instead of $i$)

Comment: My background is Complex Analysis from Stein and Shakarchi. @AitorIribarLopez

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez I haven't tried that much yet. I know that $|f(z)| \leq 1$ so that $a+bz \leq c + dz$ but don't think that will help me any further. Other than that I tried some small things but nothing really got me anywhere, so the only actual thing I have is an idea intuitively.